# Convergence of $E(|X|^r)^{\frac{1}{r}}$

Tags: convergence-divergence, expected-value

For a random variable $X$ on $[0, 1]$ with $F(1) = 1$ and $F(x) < 1$ for all $x < 1$, show that $E(|X|^r)^{\frac{1}{r}} \to 1$ as  $r → ∞$. If $F$ is such that $F(x) < 1$ for all $x ∈ R$ and all moments exist, then show $E(|X|^r)^{\frac{1}{r}} \to \infty$ as  $r → ∞$.

Can someone provide a hint?

Comment: Have you considered integration by parts

Comment: In general $E(|X|^r)^{\frac{1}{r}} \to \|X\|_{\infty}$. This has been proved many times on this site.

Comment: @geetha290krm I haven't been introduced to that yet.